# PHP Content-Type not displaying bar code image

Tags: php, html, barcode, content-type

I am trying to generate bar code using [http://www.barcodebakery.com](http://www.barcodephp.com/en) but my script is not displaying bar code image. Here is my code:

```
<?php 

require_once('../barcodegen/class/BCGFontFile.php');
require_once('../barcodegen/class/BCGColor.php');
require_once('../barcodegen/class/BCGDrawing.php');
require_once('../barcodegen/class/BCGcode128.barcode.php');


//$font = new BCGFontFile('./barcodegen/class/font/Arial.ttf', 18);
$color_black = new BCGColor(0, 0, 0);
$color_white = new BCGColor(255, 255, 255);

// Barcode Part
$code = new BCGcode128();
$code->setScale(2);
$code->setThickness(30);
$code->setForegroundColor($color_black);
$code->setBackgroundColor($color_white);
//$code->setFont($font);
$code->setStart(NULL);
$code->setTilde(true);
$code->parse('123456');

// Drawing Part
$drawing = new BCGDrawing('', $color_white);
$drawing->setBarcode($code);
$drawing->draw();


header('Content-Type: image/png');

$drawing->finish(BCGDrawing::IMG_FORMAT_PNG);

?>
```

Is there anything that I am missing? 
when I print  $drawing I get value `‰PNG  IHDRÊO%zÍ”LtEXtCopyrightGenerated with Barcode Generator for PHP http://www.barcodephp.comYp¸³IDATxœíØÑnƒ †QXöþ¯Ì.LQa¶ÝŸ.åœ«q2óµtZk¥”Zëþóf9ÏìöçžŽÎ¯x>«ŸÓ›¯áþÚæW¼sîÿæù ïßáùÌÑ çwr4çÑ¿ñëòð'äE¼’Aò"H^É‹ y$/‚äE¼’Aò"H^É‹ y$/‚äE¼’Aò"H^É‹ y$/‚äE¼’Aò"H^É‹ y$/‚äE¼’Aò"H^É‹ y$/‚äE¼’Aò"H^É‹ y$/‚äE¼’Aò"H^É‹ y$/‚äE¼ª­µw¯e÷"H^É‹ y$/‚äEÐ÷»ð¯ÕZK)ço7Ûø¦?Ú_ž¸»×Ð¡•Ãxkm«gŸÖ-ËgÕkóýi>rçÐ"V8Žg£íç~+Ú*‹çu( ÖZëcÛùeC{”‹·U÷Ú_’ž3ÚŸ¼{íì^/;©³µöÄvøaÖÍkô’þÜ¹\ZúáØ{½­m¯úuÚR–Þº_ú Fÿ3Ž*¼<ºò½Ý,iŽýb>ÌžúIEND®B`‚`

but header('Content-Type: image/png') is not displaying any image but just a small icon.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be working as it follows the examples from the [User Guide](http://www.barcodebakery.com/en/resources/guide/php/saving-barcodes).

Why are you trying to print `$drawing`? Just open the page in your browser and you should see the generated Barcode. As they explain

> If you have specified a filename before, the image will be saved into this file, otherwise it will be displayed.

So, if you want it to be saved somewhere, just add a filename when needed.

```
$drawing = new BCGDrawing('/route/to/your/file.png', $colorBack);
```